# How to swap members of two arrays so that the difference of sum of the elements of both arrays be minimum?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two unordered arrays `array1` and `array2`, both of length `LEN`. for any `i` `(0<=i<LEN)`, I can swap the values of `array1[i]` and `array2[i]`. Now, I have to swap them in a way so that the difference between sum of elements of `array1` and `array2` be minimum.

For Example:

```
array1=[1, 3, 5]
array2=[2, 4, 9]
```

Now, if I swap third member of both arrays (5 and 9), the difference becomes (1+3+9)-(2+4+5)=2.

I have found a solution using recursion. In my solution, I check all the valid combinations and where the difference is minimum, that is my answer. But here the runtime complexity is `O(2^LEN)`. How can I do it more efficiently?

P.S. Array index starts at 0.

Comment: You can swap only once or multiple times?

Comment: as many times as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a third array where the `ith` entry is the absolute difference of the `ith` values in `array1` and `array2`.  Assigning signs to these differences in the new array is equivalent to deciding whether or not you are swapping the values in your original arrays.  You are now trying to solve the problem of minimising the sum of the (potentially sign swapped) values in the third array.  This is the optimisation version of the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: How can I minimise the sum of the (potentially sign swapped) values in the third array? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Minimising the sum of the values is the optimisation version of the Partition Problem.  It is NP-hard and comprehensive details are given in the wikipedia article.